# Re-Run the program on GAE after it completes execution

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an endpoint `/` on which some specific code is supposed to run again after it completes its execution. Its similar to infinite loop. But I have no clue as to how to make it happen on GAE.

I have deployed a service `poll`. But I am unable to send automated requests once the program completes its execution. Is there anyway I can achieve this on GAE ?

I can't use cron job because the program might take longer than time set on cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Push queue](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#push_queues) Task request to trigger your code execution. When the code completes it would just enqueue another such task, which will again trigger the code, etc.

More details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39252758/4495081

Comment: Thanks Dan. Looks Push queue will solve my problem. I was also looking at achieving this using PubSub mechanism - making a push subscription. What do you think about this ?

Comment: Can't really say, I didn't think about the PubSub concept much yet. It might be overkill as your case appears to be a 1:1 producer/consumer scenario. And possibly adding complexity to the app since PubSub would be using services external to GAE (the task queue support is internal).

Comment: But Task queues isn't supported in Flexible environment (developing in Python). Is there any way I can use Task queues in here ?

Comment: I came across migrating an app to flexible and use standard's env features using `python-compat`. I'll try to use this as I am not sure how to use it...

Comment: I was a about to point you to that very guide :) For others who may read this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app. Yes, task queues are supported. Unfortunately endpoints are listed as not supported, so you may have to build 2 separate services/modules - a standard one for the endpoints, which just pushes tasks in the queue and a flexible one handling the tasks.